# Trying to create a Login form but not able to render Form inside a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a form should be inside a div .i am using Reactjs
Div structure

```
<div class="header header-primary text-center" id="content1">
    <h4>Login using ADID credentials</h4>
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/JS/Tutorial.jsx")"></script>
```

Form design which should be inside the the above div

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <div class="content">
    design structure....
  </div>
</form>

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('content1');
);
```

But the form design is not getting inside the div any idea would be appreciated..

Comment: I don't see the form being passed into `React.render`, instead you are passing a `NameForm` component. Perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: @JonKoops no i have created a class component  NameForm like this               class NameForm extends React.Component {...} but i did n't mention it since the code becomes large ...

Comment: It's always good to include a concise and reproducible code example, leaving people to infer what you mean often only complicates things and might prevent your question from being answered.